# Rename droidmote linux gamepad

Tags: debian, android, games, joystick

I'm using the Droidmote Android app to use my tablet as a gamepad for my odroid c2 (similar to raspberry pi but uses arm64 architecture.) running debian jessie. I intend to use 2 Android devices for a 2-player game of supertuxkart. Jstest-gtk recognizes them as 2 separate controllers, js0 and js1. But supertuxkart sees them as droidmote x2 and they function as 1 controller. How could I make this work? It seems it would work if I renamed one controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is strange. Maybe you could try this:

1. Connect first android device and map the controls in supertuxkart.
2. Disconnect first device and connect second device and map controls in supertuxkart.
3. Reconnect first device and see if it worked.

If nothing works, maybe try contacting the supertuxkart developers to see what their view on the issue is? Maybe they've incorrectly implemented joystick support.

Comment: Supertuxkart only works with the devices connected on startup. Also, note that it does recognize that there are two of them and shows up as droidmote x2.  I think it is an issue with the controllers having the same name. I will still try again.